# Angular2 different route parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to have multiple functions in my appication activated through different parameters. The problem is that I have to distinguish between the routes. At the moment I need these routes:

- `/employee-management/department/new`
- `/employee-management/department/delete`,
- `/employee-management/employee/new`,
- `/employee-management/employee/delete`
- `/employee-management/employee/<id>`

Here is my current implementation. But I am doing something wrong. As example when I do `/employee/new` it goes into the first `if` with the `if(params['id'])` instead of the `if(params['option'])` where it should go because new is an option not an id.

I know I am doing many things wrong here but I am stuck. Can you help me?

**Routes**

```
export const EmployeeManagementRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{
path: 'employee-management',
component: EmployeeManagementComponent,
children: [
  { 
    path: '',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: ':type/:id',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: ':type/:option',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  }
]
}
];
```

**Parameter distinguishing**

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
        //Success    
        params => {  
            this.logger.log("Param "+params);
                let type = params['type'];
                this.logger.log("Type "+type);
                if(type === "employee"){
                    if(params['option']){
                        let option = params['option'];
                        this.logger.log("Option "+option);
                        this.doEmployeeOption(option);

                    }else if(params['id']){
                        let id = params['id'];
                        this.logger.log("ID "+id);
                        this.editEmployee(id);
                    }
                }else if(type === "department"){
                    if(params['option']){
                        let option = params['option'];
                        this.logger.log("Option "+option);
                        this.doDepartmentOption(option);
                    }
                }
        },
        //Error
        err => this.logger.error(err),
        //Complete
        () => {}
    );

 doEmployeeOption(option: String){

    switch(option){
    case 'new':
        this.newEmployee = true;
        this.employee = new Employee();
        break;
    case 'delete':

        break;
    default:
        this.logger.log("Default");
        break;
    }

}
```

Sorry for the lots of input to read. But I appreciate everyone who is reading it.

Comment: your 2nd and third route are same, eventually they will result into a conflict `path: ':type/:id'` will be overriden by `path: ':type/:option'` because you are having same pattern, rather I'd say use this `{ 
    path: 'department/:option',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: 'employee/:option',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  }`

Comment: Yes I know. And it is not working. But I cannot find a solution for this problem. Have you got an idea how I should declare my routes?

Comment: I'd say have dedicated route for `employee` & `department` like I shown in my last comment..

Comment: Oh sorry I have not seen that you edited your comment. I already did this but how do I access the parameters which now are not variable anymore like `employee` and `department` now? Before I could do this with `params['type']`.

Comment: But in this case `employee/:id` and `employee/:option` would be the same structure again or am I wrong?

Comment: you can have that again, its defining same pattern, If you want it in that way only you can have `employee/:id` & `employee/action/:type`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot map two path with the same exact segments as parameter. However, you can manually dispatch to the correct component. You can for exemple use this code.

### Routes

```
export const EmployeeManagementRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{
path: 'employee-management',
component: EmployeeManagementComponent,
children: [
  { 
    path: '',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: ':type/:param',  
    component: EmployeeManagementTableComponent 
  }
]
}
];
```

### Parameter dispatch

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {  
            this.logger.log("Param "+params);
                let type = params['type'];
                this.logger.log("Type "+type);
                let p = params['params'];
                if(type === "employee"){
                    if(p.match(/\d+/)){
                        let id = +p;
                        this.logger.log("ID "+id);
                        this.editEmployee(id);
                    } else {
                        let option = p;
                        this.logger.log("Option "+option);
                        this.doEmployeeOption(option);  
                    }
                }else if(type === "department"){
                    if(p){
                        let option = p;
                        this.logger.log("Option "+option);
                        this.doDepartmentOption(option);
                    }
                }
        },
        //Error
        err => this.logger.error(err),
        //Complete
        () => {}
    );
```

Comment: That would also be a great solution. With `p.match()` you check if p is a decimal or not right?

Comment: @moessi774 I check if it match the regexp \d+ (only digits).