# Angular 2 accessing the same route with different param doesn't reload it

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I'm trying to access player profile it works, and I find myself in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/player-profile/5
```

From this route, trying to navigate to another player profile, for example:

```
http://localhost:4200/player-profile/2
```

no longer works.
the URL in the browser changes but the component is not refreshing to the new param infromation.

How I can reload the player profile when user trying to access different profile?

Comment: You have to provide code where you try to access route param in your component.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103859/angular2-different-route-parameters