# Angular 2 route with url parameter conflicts with other routes

Tags: angular, routes

My child module routes are as follows,

```
{
  path: '',
  children: [
    { path: '', component: TripManagerComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: TripDetailComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: TripNewComponent }
  ]
}
```

I am navigating to these routes as follows,

```
navigateToTrip(index: number) {
  this.router.navigate([index], { relativeTo: this.route });
}

navigateToNewTrip() {
  this.router.navigate(['new'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

But Angular detects `new` route as `:id` and navigates me to `TripDetailComponent`.

The problem here is Angular detects 'new' string as url parameter for `:id` route.

I could add a prefix to `:id`, i.e. `view/:id` and make this work. But, I need to keep the url pattern as it is. Is there a way to do this?

My expected url pattern is,

```
/trips        --> show all trips
/trips/2334   --> show details of trip 2334
/trips/new    --> show a form to create a new trip
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently you `:id` route matches also with `new` and the router doesn't look further for other matching routes.

The order is relevant. Move the `new` route before the `:id` route, then the `new` route matches before the `:id` route.

```
{
  path: '',
  children: [
    { path: '', component: TripManagerComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: TripNewComponent }
    { path: ':id', component: TripDetailComponent },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Günter. It works. Never thought the order would matter.

Comment: Routes order always gets me :| thanks for clarifying this up.

Comment: How we can manage the complete dynamic kind of URL, without any section.

Comment: what are the chances you have an :id that matches 'new'.  Can we ignore this possibility ? 

Comment: @VaisakhRajagopal No, in this case the id `new` will never match because the `'new'` rule will always match earlier. You could change the order, but then you have the problem the other way around. Basically you need to ensure to not use ids or literal paths that potentially conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map two path with the same exact segments as parameter (*:id* matches the *new* path).

However, you can map manually the correct action with the following configuration.

```
{
  path: '',
  children: [
    { path: '', component: TripManagerComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: TripDetailComponent },
  ]
}
```

Into the component `TripDetailComponent`, you can trigger the creation process if the parameter is equal to new.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {  
                let id = params['id'];
                if (id === "new") {
                    // Create a new element
                } else if(p.match(/\d+/)){
                    // Display the details
                } else {
                    // Handle when id is not a number
                }
        },
        // Handle error
        err => this.logger.error(err),
        //Complete
        () => {}
    );
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104170/1630604) is related to this one.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. This is a little complex solution than Günter's solution. But I believe I might encounter situations where I need to use this method to load components when the app grows.